# A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected, but ValidateInput is false

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

Good morning! I Have an issue with a wysiwyg editor that saves html to my database. On my news articles page, it works fine. I have

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

in my web.config, and

```
[ValidateInput(False)]
```

above my edit http post action, and yet my other page with the same wysiwyg editor is rejecting my request with the yellow screen of death saying I need to enable all of these settings.

Does anybody know why this would be happening on one page but not the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure this is the problem, could be just a typo or not an issue but whenever I have used the `ValidateInput` attribute, I have it as lower case `false`:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
```

Also verify that the controller method you decorated is actually the one being used by the `Post`.

Answer (score 1):

If your using Html.RenderAction you must also disable validation on those pages as well.